# ImagickException UnableToLoadModule IM_MOD_RL_PDF_.dll

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll, imagemagick

I have problem with imagick with XAMPP.
My installation:

> - XAMPP v5.5.24
> - Operating Windows.

I install `php_imagick.dll`, and copy all `[imagemagic_dir]\modules\coders\*.dll` to `XAMPP\apache\bin`.

And then show error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'UnableToLoadModule `C:\xampp\apache\bin\IM_MOD_RL_PDF_.dll' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wptest\wp-content\plugins\pdf-image-generator\pdf-image-generator.php
>   on line 50

Comment: Double check ImageMagick & XAMPP are 32-bit (x86).

Comment: yes, both already 32-bit version